# Set-ADAccountPassword -PassThru

Tags: powershell

Using Set-ADAccountPassword normally you don't get any output. The get-help of Set-ADAccountPassword says there is a -PassThru parameter to "Return the new or modified object" however I can't get any output at all.

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity <username> -Reset -NewPassword -PassThru (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "TempP@$$W0rd" -Force)
```

The command works, but there is no output. I'd like to get it working singularly first, and then eventually use Get-ADUser to pipe an OU of users to Set-ADAccountPassword and display the list of objects that were modified. I just can't understand why -PassThru appears to do nothing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Place -passthru at the end of the command and watch out for those quotes around TempP@$$W0rd. The double quotes allow for [variable expansion in the string](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-herestrings.aspx). $$ is an [automatic variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) representing the last token in the last line powershell received. This may make your password something completely different than what you think it is.

Example

---

```
PS:>Get-ChildItem C:\
PS:>"TempP@$$W0rd"
TempP@C:\W0rd
```

Single quote it instead. I'm not at a computer with the AD module on it but this should work.

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity <username> -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText 'TempP@$$W0rd' -Force) -PassThru
```

Here's a [good article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/18/use-the-powershell-passthru-parameter-and-get-back-objects.aspx) that explains -PassThru

Comment: Thank you for the double quotes tip. I tried putting -PassThru at the end and it made no difference. I also tried with a non-variable, non complex password. Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity <username> -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText 'anewpasswd' -Force) -PassThru and I still get no return. Any Ideas?

Comment: I dont have the AD module and can't install it here. I'll get back to you this evening. ~8 hours from now

Comment: Hi, were you able to give it a go? I still can't work out why I get no output

Comment: I've tested this on 2 domains. On one domain the passthru works as expected, I get an object and I can pipe it along to Get-ADUser or whatever I like. On the other domain however I get no output at all, exactly as you described. I cannot for the life of me figure out what the difference is. Sorry I can't be of more help, but I'm stumped as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've been battling this all morning and can't seem to get any output from -PassThru either.  I'd be interested to see what the difference is between those it works for and those it doesn't.  I'm running this with PS4.0 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Domain.

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $UserDN -Credential $AdminCred -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Pass -Force) -PassThru
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-imaging my machine from Win7 which then had ps v3 and later v4 installed on it, to Win8 which obviously comes with ps v4. Ran the same script and it worked.

Perhaps somewhere along the upgrade path something broke.